# how i can add the attribute of extra_tag in class_based_views in django

Tags: python, django, class, view, message

how I can add the attribute of "extra_tag" in class_based_views in django.
In normal views we are using like this:

```
messages.success(request, 'Product is added successfully', extra_tags='alert-primary')
```

but in generic views how we can write it?
**views.py**

```
class EditProduct(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = EditProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('stock:stock')
    template_name = 'stock/editproduct.html'
    success_message = "Product is updated successfully."

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.saler =  self.request.user
        form.instance.pub_date = timezone.now()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Thank you for your help.